# Proof that a transitive permutation group (G, X) with G abelian, is sharply regular

Tags: permutations, abelian-groups

As the title states, the question is the following: *Let (G, X) be a transitive permutation group, where G is abelian. Show that (G, X) is "sharply regular".*

First of all I want to notice that in my course we never saw what *"sharply regular"* means in relation to permutation groups. Wikipedia however, tells me that my professor perhaps meant *"sharply transitive"*, so I'm going to solve the question assuming he meant this. Please tell me if it's possible that he meant something else.

**Proof:** So, I need to prove that: $\forall x, y \in X, \exists! g \in G: x^g = y$

Given that (G, X) is a transitive permutation group, we know already that there exists at least one such g. Now we have to show that there exists *just* one such g.

Suppose that there exists $h \in G: x^h = y$ as well.
Then $x^{gh^{-1}} = y^{h^{-1}} = x$.
Therefore it is clear that $gh^{-1} \in kernel$. (G, X) is a permutation group, which means that the kernel is trivial. Therefore: $gh^{-1} = e$. Now it is clear that g = h and the question is solved.

**However**, in this proof I did not use the fact that G is abelian. Something tells me that they gave me this information on purpose. So I assume I have made a mistake somewhere in my proof. Could anyone point out the mistake and perhaps show me how to proof this using the fact that G is commutative?

Comment: The issue with your proof if that you only conclude that $gh^{-1}$ fixes this one element. This does not imply that it fixes everything.

Comment: Thank you for this remark. I knew it had to be something elementary.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in X$, and $G_{x}$ be the stabilizer of $x$. Since $G$ acts transitively, for any $y \in X$, there will be $g \in G$ such that $x^{g} = y$. Thus $G_{y} = G_{x^{g}} = (G_{x})^{g} = G_{x}$, as $G$ is abelian. Hence $G_{x}$ fixes all elements of $X$, so that $G_{x}$ is trivial.

Finish it by noting that if $y = x^{g}$, then the set of elements $h \in G$ such that $y = x^{h}$ is the coset $G_{x} g$.